# Looping through an array and setting each element as a property of an object messes with the order

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, properties

I have an array containing some IDs:

```
let ids = [ '184', '085', '241', '086', '087', '165' ];
```

and an empty object - `let data = {};`

I am looping through the array and setting each of the elements as a property of the object:

```
ids.forEach(id => {
    data[id] = '';
});
```

I expect the data object to be:

```
{ '184': '', '085': '', '241': '', '086': '', '087': '', '165': '' }
```

But when I `console.log(data)` I find that the order of the properties is messed up and `data` is:

```
{ '165': '', '184': '', '241': '', '085': '', '086': '', '087': '' }
```

I have tried looping through the array with this method also:

```
for (let id of ids) {
    data[id] = '';
}
```

But the same messed-up order results. I need to know *how* can I set the properties in correct order and, more importantly, *what* is causing this issue.

Comment: Objects aren't ordered data structures - you access their content by prop name, not index. If order matters, keep the array.

Comment: As jonrsharpe said - this wont be possible as object keys themselves are never ordered. May I ask you why you want them in an ordered fashion? Do you need to do anything with them in a certain order?

Comment: @DavidLosert Actually, object keys do have a defined order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @jonrdharpe I thought I had read somewhere that now object properties do have an order. That order is insertion based , i.e oldest inserted property coming before the recent insertions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Map` instead to maintain insertion order. Object keys are ordered in insertion order, except for numeric keys which are ordered in ascending order.

```js
let ids = [ '184', '085', '241', '086', '087', '165' ];
const map = new Map;
ids.forEach(id => map.set(id, ''));
map.forEach((val,key)=>console.log(key,'=',val));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @hev1 for this answer. Works like a charm! Also, I didn't know about Maps, so thanks for that also!

Comment: doesn't `new Map;`  need to be `new Map();` ?